# Parsing header of email text

Tags: python, regex

I have a small snippet of a text file which represents an email.

```
s="""Joe Hillings@ENRON
09/08/99 02:52 PM
To: Joe Hillings/Corp/Enron@Enron
cc: Sanjay Bhatnagar/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Terence H 
Thorn/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Ashok 
Mehta/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, John 
Ambler/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Steven J Kean/HOU/EES@EES, 
Jeffrey Sherrick/Corp/Enron@Enron 
Subject: Re: India And The WTO Services Negotiation  
"""
```

I want to extract each header ("From, "To", "cc", "Subject") of the email (including the time above)

To test out, I am trying to extract To and cc field for above string.

I do that as below:

```
regex=r"To:(?P<To>.*)\ncc:(?P<cc>.*)"

res=re.search(regex,s,re.M)

print("To: {}".format(res.group("To")))
print("cc: {}".format(res.group("cc")))
```

**Output:**

```
To:  Joe Hillings/Corp/Enron@Enron
cc:  Sanjay Bhatnagar/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Terence H
```

It seems to work, but only picks the data corresponding to one line and ignores all other data in other line for the same header. Like for 'cc' only first line is picked.

If I add "Subject" header in regex now it throws an error

```
regex1=r"To:(?P<To>.*)\ncc:(?P<cc>.*)\nSubject:(?P<Subject>.*)"

res=re.search(regex1,s,re.M)
print("To: {}".format(res.group("To")))
print("cc: {}".format(res.group("cc")))
```

**Output:**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any help where I am going wrong and why would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

For multiple emails in a txt file, the answer suggested below currently only extracts header of last email in file and ignores the previous emails in the txt file.

```
s1="""Message-ID: <28937390.1075853126342.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2001 06:54:59 -0700 (PDT)
From: michelle.cash@enron.com
To: rob.walls@enron.com
Subject: RE: Confidential Concern
Cc: sharon.butcher@enron.com, a..hope@enron.com
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Bcc: sharon.butcher@enron.com, a..hope@enron.com
X-From: Cash, Michelle </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=MCASH>
X-To: Walls Jr., Rob </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Rwalls>
X-cc: Butcher, Sharon </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Sbutche>, Hope, Valeria A. </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Vhope>
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \MCASH (Non-Privileged)\Cash, Michelle\Sent Items
X-Origin: Cash-M
X-FileName: MCASH (Non-Privileged).pst

Sharon, I suggest that we ask Valeria Hope to investigate the fact situation here and report back to us jointly.  What do you think?  Michelle

 -----Original Message-----
From:Walls Jr., Rob  
Sent:Wednesday, July 25, 2001 5:53 PM
To: Cash, Michelle
Cc: Butcher, Sharon
Subject:FW: Confidential Concern

Michelle -

Since this is in Venezuela and thus part of wholesale, I am sending you a copy of this letter for you to review.  I'm not sure who should take the lead between you and Sharon but I'll leave that to you guys to work out.  Please let me know who is taking the lead on this.  Thanks.

 -----Original Message-----
From:   Sera, Sherri   On Behalf Of Office of the Chairman,
Sent:   Wednesday, July 25, 2001 10:54 AM
To: Fleming, Rosalee; Clark, Mary
Cc: Butcher, Sharon; Walls Jr., Rob; Kean, Steven J.
Subject:    Confidential Concern

I'm not sure I understand what has happened to this guy, but it's something that should be handled post haste.  Thanks, SRS
---------------------- Forwarded by Sherri Sera/Corp/Enron on 07/25/2001 10:52 AM ---------------------------

 << OLE Object: Picture (Device Independent Bitmap) >> 
Anonymous

From:   Anonymous on 07/23/2001 02:08 PM
To: 
cc:  

Subject:    Confidential Concern


 << File: Ken Lay - Jeff Skilling.doc >> 

"""
```

**Output (Edit section):**

```
Time:  07/23/2001 02:08 PM
To:     
cc:      


    Confidential Concern
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follow:

```
import re

s="""Joe Hillings@ENRON
09/08/99 02:52 PM
To: Joe Hillings/Corp/Enron@Enron
cc: Sanjay Bhatnagar/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Terence H 
Thorn/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Ashok 
Mehta/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, John 
Ambler/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Steven J Kean/HOU/EES@EES, 
Jeffrey Sherrick/Corp/Enron@Enron 
Subject: Re: India And The WTO Services Negotiation  
"""
#regex=r"To:(?P<To>.*)\ncc:(?P<cc>.*)"
regex=r"(.|\n)*?(?P<xtime>[\d\/: ]+(AM|PM))\nTo:(?P<To>.*)\ncc:(?P<cc>(.|\n)*?)Subject:(?P<Subject>.*)"

res=re.search(regex,s,re.M)

print("time: {}".format(res.group("xtime")))
print("To: {}".format(res.group("To")))
print("cc: {}".format(res.group("cc")))
print("Subject: {}".format(res.group("Subject")))
```

To pass many line, you have to use `(.|\n)*`, and the mark `?` for non greedy include!

Comment: This is better, but "cc" still gives only the first line data. 

To:  Joe Hillings/Corp/Enron@Enron
cc:  Sanjay Bhatnagar/ENRON_DEVELOPMENT@ENRON_DEVELOPMENT, Terence H 
 Re: India And The WTO Services Negotiation


  Also any idea how can one extract the date time above ?

Comment: It's safer, if you tell me the format of time, for not miss with any digit at begin mail!

Comment: Well I don't know the format of time actually. It's what we have in the email corpus. Typically should be like this only.

Comment: If I have multiple such emails in the same text file, then using same regular exp but findall instead of search will give me one by one extraction of each email? I basically want to store all these header of each email as columns of a row (a row is one email) in a csv/pandas dataframe.

Comment: With this problem, I assume time is digit sequences before "AM" or "PM", I updated my regex python code! Another things, sorry, I have just started Python some days ago!

Comment: Including `(.|\n)*?` at the start of a such long pattern will cause a regex tinmeout sooner than later. Never use `(.|\n)*?` in any regex engine (except Lucene) when you need to match any char. In Python, there is `re.S`.

Comment: Normally, a email always has short content, so the regex execute time, is not a problem!

Comment: So there are few issues. First, it only picks the last email headers. In a text file I have multiple emails. See the edit. It doesn't pick headers from all the other emails and only picks from the last email. Thats an issue as I need headers for all emails in a txt file